# Curl post, without waiting for response

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do a *curl* post, but without receiving the response.
I know I can prevent the response from being displayed by setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to false, but I don't even want to receive it.

I am working on a proxy and need to do the post request to a webservice, but the response it gives is MASSIVE and ends up timing out my connection (even when set to 200 seconds).

Even if it did work, that's just way too long since I don't care what the response is at all.

I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: If you could do this, it could be used in a DOS attack. If you find a way to do it, you should report it to the devs of whatever service you are calling.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a socket rather than using cURL:

```
$requestBody = 'myparams=something&something=somethingelse';

$socket = fsockopen("mysite.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 15);

if (!$socket) {
    // Handle the error, can't connect
} else {
    $http  = "POST /path/to/post/to HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $http .= "Host: mysite.com\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_data) . "\r\n";
    $http .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $http .= $requestBody . "\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($socket, $http);

    fclose($socket);
}
```

This will submit the POST request and not wait around for the response.

Comment: Hi, Tomdarkness.
i have implement the function using socket but it not execute the url code. can you please help to solve this issue.